# Disable file preview for a custom file type in iOS

Tags: ios, file, ios5, ios6

I have associated a file type with my iOS app, so I can open files of that type in the app, e.g. from an email. Opening files works, but simply tapping on an attachment in an email opens the quick view screen, which comes up blank. The file format is a zip file with a custom extension, which I believe is unique.

What can I do to disable the quick view for my file type?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you came up with a solution since :)

For people who may be searching for a solution too, have a look on the protocol(s) you custom type inherits from (array key ***UTTypeConformsTo***, name "Conforms to UTIs")

In my case, my custom type is a zip archive with a custom extension (as you) and I put "*public.data*" and "*public.archive*".
The "public.archive" was responsible for the OS to display the content of my custom zip in Files app, or having the Quick look in Mail app.
The solution was to inherit only from "public.data".